# How to declare variables and sum up the variable values

Tags: excel, vba, addition

Hi I would like to sum these 3 variables and auto-populate the sum value to another variable - txtTotalMonthly Salary on Excel.

1. txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary
2. txtAWS
3. txtAllowance

Could anyone advise please?

```
Private Sub txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary_Change()

If Me.txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary.Value <> "" Then
    Dim Product As Long
    Product = Me.txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary.Value * 12

    Me.txtLastAnnualDrawnSalary.Value = Product
End If

If Me.txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary.Value <> "" Then
    Dim Sum As Long

  Me.txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary.Value Me.txtAWS.Value + Me.txtAllowance.Value = Sum

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your quesion? You've posted some code - does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as good practice, I would declare the variables all at the beginning.

so start with DIM product ect...
also, what is "Me"

Also, If txtlastmonthdrawnsalary is numeric, you don't need to add ".value" at the end.

Just to avoid any possible errors I added "z" at the end of your variable to distiguish them from VB coomands.

I would start with the following, if that still doesn't work, let's see where it breaks:

```
Private Sub txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary_Change()
    Dim Productz As Long, Sumz As Long, txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary as long, txtLastAnnualDrawnSalary as long

    If not txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary = "" Then

        Productz = txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary * 12

        txtLastAnnualDrawnSalary = Productz
    End If

    If not txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary = "" Then


      sumz = txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary +  txtAWS + txtAllowance 

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: No problem. Also you can shorten your code using the following, since the if criteria is the same:

Private Sub txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary_Change()
    Dim Productz As Long, Sumz As Long, txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary as long, txtLastAnnualDrawnSalary as long

    If not txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary = "" Then

        Productz = txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary * 12

        txtLastAnnualDrawnSalary = Productz

      sumz = txtLastMonthlyDrawnSalary +  txtAWS + txtAllowance 

    End If

    End Sub